# Execute Text Box_TextChanged Event in Asp.Net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to implement validations on textbox like if null then display a message to fill the empty field and to check the length of the text entered. I have written the code for it inside TextBox_TextChanged event but it's not working. The event is not getting fired and the user can is able to signup without a username, that is my problem at the moment. Do I have to trigger the event manually? Here is a glimpse of what I am doing:

```
protected void FirstN_TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String firstNameEntered = FirstN_TextBox.Text;
        if (firstNameEntered != null)
        {
            if (firstNameEntered.Length <= 20)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Inside text box");
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
        else
        {
            FirstN_TextBox.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill the marked field");
        }
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForm? How are you using on the client side (.asp or .aspx files)? I will suggest using JavaScript instead of C# code behind.

Comment: if you are using asp.net this MessageBox.Show can't be done.

Comment: without username???? use requirefieldvalidators

Comment: @reds I havn't changed anything inside the HTML code but still if you want to see:

<asp:TextBox ID="FirstN_TextBox" placeholder="First name" runat="server" Width="225px" OnTextChanged="FirstN_TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: show it.. I must check

Comment: @reds dont worry about Messagebox.Show. My point is why it's not validating?

Comment: @RK_Aus Yes, I am using Webforms. Javascript can be disabled at browser level so that is why I am implementing it in Code behind file.

Comment: @Deep - Text change event will get fired if the text box is in focus. What if you do all the validations on submit button click?

Comment: @RK_Aus I already didi that but rather, I want to trigger the events of all the textboxes. It will make the code less complex and will be easy to understand.

Comment: Basically, answer provided by @reds must work (AutoPostBack ="true"). Pressing the ENTER or the TAB key while in the TextBox control will trigger the event. TextChanged event occurs when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server. Use the AutoPostBack property to specify whether an automatic postback to the server will occur when the TextBox control loses focus. I will suggest best to use JavaScript for client-side validation. If JavaScript is disabled, many of the websites won't work and may be a rare scenario.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @RK_Aus I will work on it as well. How about this if I implement validations on both server and client side? Will it effect the performance of my site as it will have millions of users? It has to be highly secured so that is why  I am concerned about its security.

Comment: Yes, server side validations will affect performance as in the Server Side Validation, the input submitted by the user is being sent to the server. In the Client Side Validation, you can provide a better user experience by responding quickly at the browser level. Server side validations are more secure. The choice depends on the priority. If security is more important than user experience go with the server side validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it like this:

**From:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstN_TextBox" placeholder="First name" runat="server" Width="225px"   OnTextChanged="FirstN_TextBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

**To:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="FirstN_TextBox" placeholder="First name" runat="server" Width="225px"   OnTextChanged="FirstN_TextBox_TextChanged" AutoPostBack ="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Clean and build your project after you change it.

Comment: I have done the same but still validation not working.

Comment: Its tested before i post. don't know what you did. try to check spaces and remove

Comment: I have done exactly the same but didn't work. So I switched to validate controls. But I appreciate your time and efforts. Thanks.... :)

Comment: do you want to try keypress event?

Comment: even that's not working. It's not even showing that event. I don't know what's wrong.